# How to find Mac documents path (language independent)

Tags: macos, go, path, system-paths

I need to find the documents folder path using golang on MacOS. I can do like this:

```
docsPath := os.Getenv("HOME") + "/Documents"
```

But I don't know if "Documents" is a valid solution for other OS languages. What if the Mac is Italian language? Is there a way to find out for sure? Or where can I find the proven information that it is always "Documents"? Sadly I do not have access to any Mac other than English.

Comment: According to [this](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3014097), it looks like the directory name is always the same, but the localized version can be configured for display purposes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MacOS places all user files and folders to `/Users/%username%/`, e.g. for me `/Users/lisitsky`.
Documents are located at subfolder `/Users/username/Documents`. You look at it name in terminal by `ls /Users/username/Documents`.

Finder shows localized names for standard folders in your language but uses standard names on system level.

Also you may check `os/user` module.

```
 func main() {    
    usr, _ := user.Current()
    dir := usr.HomeDir
    fmt.Println(dir, path.Join(dir, "Documents"))
 }
```

Comment: I don't think this answers the question, which is what is `Documents` called in different languages.

Comment: If I got right, the question was about finding system path of Documents folder. It is  is the same on all localized systems and is `/Users/username/Documents` regardless of localization. For example, on one of machines I have Russian locale and my folder is shown as `Документы` in Finder, but system path is the same `~/Documents`.

Comment: I would suggest making that point in the answer--that the system path doesn't depend on language.